# Select element added with function

Tags: javascript, selector

first of all sorry if my english isn't my native language.

I'm just starting to learn JS and i'm trying to create a basic todolist on codepen (https://codepen.io/Jonathan_Design/pen/OJwqXrO) but i'm stuck cause I don't know how to select an element added with JS (not on the base of the document).

I tried :

`const trash = document.querySelector('.todolist__list__raw__trash');

trash.addEventListener('click', function(){
console.log(this);
})`

but this one only work on the first "raw" cause this one is on the html code base.

I did this but only with Jquery :

`$(document).on('click', '.todolist__list__raw__trash', function() { $(this).parent().remove(); });`

but I really want to learn it in JS :)

Thx
Jonathan

Does anyone can help me to select a element added with JS ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! jQuery is JS. try `querySelectorAll` to select all the matches (and not only the 1st) ,go over the results with a `for` loop or `.forEach`, and add an event listener to each match

Answer (score 0):

`querySelector()` only selects the first element it finds in the DOM. For more than one element, use `querySelectorAll()`.

1. Define the `trash` selector at the top with your others.
2. Make a function to get the list of trash elements, and assign an event listener to all of them.
3. Make the todoPlus event listener an anonymous function and call the `addRaw()` and the new `cleanTrash()` functions inside of it.

Now each time you add a new item, it checks the DOM for the new trash element, and adds the event listener to it.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// JAVASCRIPT
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  //SELECTEURS
const todoPlus = document.querySelector(".todolist__list__plus");
const todoRaw = document.querySelector(".todolist__list__raw:last-child");
const todoTrash = document.querySelector(".todolist__list__raw:last-child .todolist__list__raw__trash");
const todoList = document.querySelector(".todolist__list");
let trash = document.querySelectorAll('.todolist__list__raw__trash');

  //ECOUTEURS
todoPlus.addEventListener("click", () => {
  addRaw()
  cleanTrash()
});
// const todoList = document.querySelector(".todolist__list");
// todoDelete.addEventListener("click", deleteRaw);

  //FONCTIONS

function addRaw(event){
//   CREATION ELEMENT + CLASSE
  const newTodoDivRaw = document.createElement('div');
  const newTodoInputCheck = document.createElement('input');
  newTodoInputCheck.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
  const newTodoInputText = document.createElement('input');
  newTodoInputText.setAttribute("type", "text");
  newTodoInputText.setAttribute("placeholder", "Add a task ...");
  newTodoInputText.setAttribute("size", "30");
  const newTodoSpanTrash = document.createElement('span');
  const iconTrash = document.createElement('i');
  iconTrash.className = 'fa fa-trash';
// INSERTION DE LA NOUVELLE LIGNE 
  newTodoDivRaw.classList.add('todolist__list__raw');
  todoList.appendChild(newTodoDivRaw);
  newTodoInputCheck.classList.add('todolist__list__raw__checkbox');
  newTodoDivRaw.appendChild(newTodoInputCheck);
  newTodoInputText.classList.add('todolist__list__raw__text');
  newTodoDivRaw.appendChild(newTodoInputText);
  newTodoSpanTrash.classList.add('todolist__list__raw__trash');
  newTodoDivRaw.appendChild(newTodoSpanTrash);
  newTodoSpanTrash.appendChild(iconTrash);
}

  // SUPPRESION DE LA RAW

function cleanTrash() {
  trash = document.querySelectorAll('.todolist__list__raw__trash');
  trash.forEach((t) => {
    t.addEventListener('click', function(){
     console.log(this);
    })
  })
}
```